# How to parse ical file(.ics) with ical4j API?

Tags: android, file, parsing

Anyone have idea of parsing the ical calendar file with ical4j API for android app using eclipse as development environment.

I have added ical4j API, to my project, but getting some errors related to API.

Answer (score 1):

Setting these properties in your code or passed as VM arguments should solve the problem

```
-Dical4j.unfolding.relaxed=true 
-Dical4j.parsing.relaxed=true
```

Answer (score 0):

modify build path..ical4j jar lib should be under folder called libs in your android project.
In build path dialog screen you need ot add the ical4j jar lib to project

Comment: i have done this before, but need some help to parse my ical file